# How to get "<Enter>" events for overlapping Frames?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a somewhat complex UI created with Tkinter/ttk, which contains multiple frames included in other frames.

I want the `<Enter>` event to fire when I more from the inner frame to the parent frame.

I'm already binding on the `<Leave>` event for other functions, but how can I get the "current" widget so that I can trigger a "fake" `<Enter>` event on the parent widget? But this only when leaving the child to the parent, not when leaving both child and parent at the same time (at a boundary, for example).

Here's a code sample to illustrate what I mean:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk


def onEnter(event):
    print('Widget: %s', event.widget)


class FrameTop(ttk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, text='TopFrame', **kwargs)

        for i in range(4):
            lbl_t = ttk.Label(self, text='Top Label %d' % i)
            lbl_t.pack()
        self.bottom = FrameBottom(self, 1)
        self.bottom.pack()
        self.lbl = ttk.Label(self.bottom, text='Label')
        self.lbl.pack()


class FrameBottom(ttk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, num, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, text='BottomFrame %d' % num, **kwargs)
        for i in range(5):
            lbl_t = ttk.Label(self, text='#%d: Label %d' % (num, i))
            lbl_t.pack()
        if num < 5:
            inner = FrameBottom(self, num + 1)
            inner.pack()
        self.bind('<Enter>', onEnter, add=True)  # Bind Bottom


root = tkinter.Tk()

tp = FrameTop(root)
tp.pack()

tp.bind('<Enter>', onEnter, add=True)  # Bind Bottom

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since the *parent frame* is always the holder of the *child frame*, you actually never `Leave` the parent, therefor you can not `Enter`.